# Multiple Listboxes bound to same List

Tags: c#, listbox, datasource

I am trying to bind several ListBoxs to a List.  When a ListBox on one form is updated, I want it to update the other ListBox, too.

The problem I am running into is that it doesn't seem to update the view on the ListBox when I update the underlying List.  If I look at the ListBox.Items in debug, I can see that all the items I add are there, but are not being displayed.  Additionally, when I  open another form that displays the List on a ListBox, it does correctly display whatever items had already been added.

```
private List<String> _list;

public Form1()
{
   InitializeComponent();

   _list = StaticInstanceOfList.GetInstance();
   listbox1.DataSource = _list;
}

public void AddStringToList(string value)
{
   if (!_list.Contains(value))
   {
      _list.Add(value);
   }
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try to use a [`BindingList<T>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms132679.aspx) to store your items and then assign this list to both listboxes via the [`DataSource`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.listcontrol.datasource.aspx) property.

Comment: Yes, because BindingList<T> supports change notifications (in contrast to List<T> etc.).

Comment: Check that selection is also maintained correctly. At least dropdownlistbox:es have a bug that they each require separate list as datasource to work correctly, otherwise they will synchronize among themselves in weird ways.

Answer (score 0):

Use a [bindingSource](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.bindingsource.aspx) and bind both listBoxes to that.